# Hiding folders from Specific Users

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-server-2003

I use computers in a shared house, the computers are running Windows 7 and Windows Vista and are connected to a network with Windows Server 2003 as the DC.
I want to hide certain folders from other users, and not just using the hidden folder attribute.
I know I can limit the permissions on folders to grant / deny users acees but was wondering if there is a way just not to display the folders to certain users so they don't even know they're there.
e.g. User A will see the contents of the S drive asFolder1, Folder2, Folder3. User B will see the contents of the S drive as Folder1, Folder2. 
Perhaps I'm looking at this the wrong way but any advice would be appreciated.

I'm going along the mothod of "What people don't know is there they aren't curious about"

Comment: Downvoter care to explain... No? I thought not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Access Based Enumeration](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04A563D9-78D9-4342-A485-B030AC442084&displaylang=en)

Comment: That sounds perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your looking at it the wrong way.

Just make sure you create your folder structure in such a way that users only see the folders they are meant to see when drives are mapped. The NT level security will allow you to remove complete permissions on a folder, but will not hide the folder from being seen, whether mapped or when accessing the server using network neighbourhood.

If people are not meant to see it, then put it in a place they **can't get too**.

Comment: The point is that the users think they have access to everything on the machine. I'm trying to avoid the access denied situation

Comment: @Joe How would they know if they can't see it? Are you sharing the whole drive?

Comment: The whole drive is shared. Its a raided drive on the server that all users use to keep their documents, photos etc safer than if they were just on a standard HDD . I think I'm just going to have to go with permissions but was hoping to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @Joe. Based on your accepted answer I stand corrected :)

Comment: thanks for your time anyway, I'd never even heard of access based enumeration but shall be recommending it at work too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create (and share) different directories for each users and create [junction and/or hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to only the sub-directories they could access